# Get total average of a specific column in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, window-functions

The subquery provides me with each rep's total prepaid activations for each month and outside of this subquery, I'm trying to find the average of that entire column, also for each month. How do I code this correctly for what I'm looking for?

See code below for more details, but I would like it to average the Total Prepaid ACTs based on the different EOM values for all reps so that I can compare an individual rep's performance to the total average for a given month.

Here is my current SQL code and a snip of some of the results:

```
SELECT
    *
    , AVG(PM.[Total Prepaid ACTs]) AS 'Average Prepaid'
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        WT.repid
        , ISNULL(SUM(NetPrePaidActivations), 0) AS 'Total Prepaid ACTs'
        , ISNULL(SUM(NetPostpaidIncBYOD), 0) AS 'Total Postpaid ACTs'
                , CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(SUM(AccessorySales), 0), 2) AS FLOAT) AS 'Total Acc Sales'
        , ISNULL(SUM(AccessoryUnits), 0) AS 'Total Acc Units'
        , EOMONTH(WT.ActivityDate, 0) AS 'EOM'
    FROM
        WalmartWSP.dbo.WalmartTransactions WT
    LEFT JOIN
        WalmartWSP.dbo.RepRoster RR
    ON
        WT.repid = RR.RepID
    WHERE
        WT.repid <> 0
        AND
        RR.RepHireDate BETWEEN '06-01-2022' AND '12-31-2022'
        AND
        WT.ActivityDate BETWEEN '06-01-2022' AND '12-31-2022'
    GROUP BY
        WT.repid
        , EOMONTH(WT.ActivityDate, 0)
    ) PM --ProductivityMetrics
GROUP BY
    PM.EOM
    , PM.repid
    , PM.[Total Acc Sales]
    , PM.[Total Acc Units]
    , PM.[Total Postpaid ACTs]
    , PM.[Total Prepaid ACTs]
```

Current Result (there's also a couple more columns in the result that I've left out for visibility):

```
repid   Total Prepaid ACTs    EOM           Average Prepaid
369928  5                     2022-10-31    5
373049  17                    2022-11-30    17
369579  0                     2022-10-31    0
361235  22                    2022-11-30    22
370359  6                     2022-11-30    6
```

Instead of calculating the average for each of the 'Total Prepaid ACTs' for each EOM, it's giving me the Total Prepaid ACTs value to the left and only averaging this single row.

So my desired result here would be the following:

```
repid   Total Prepaid ACTs    EOM           Average Prepaid
369928  5                     2022-10-31    2.5
373049  17                    2022-11-30    15.0
369579  0                     2022-10-31    2.5
361235  22                    2022-11-30    15.0
370359  6                     2022-11-30    15.0
```

Comment: You need to also provide the sample data that produces those desired results.

Comment: How do you do it (mathematically) correctly? Avoid the `float` and `real` data types then because they are [approximate-number types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql) and shouldn't be used anywhere at all near financial calculations.

Comment: I believe I've added all of the necessary data into my question now. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You don't appear to have added sample starting data...

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the calculation with window functions. You are describing a window average, so:

```
SELECT
    WT.repid,
    ISNULL(SUM(NetPrePaidActivations), 0),                     AS [Total Prepaid ACTs]
    ISNULL(SUM(NetPostpaidIncBYOD), 0),                        AS [Total Postpaid ACTs]
    CAST(ROUND(ISNULL(SUM(AccessorySales), 0), 2) AS FLOAT),   AS [Total Acc Sales]
    ISNULL(SUM(AccessoryUnits), 0),                            AS [Total Acc Units]
    EOMONTH(WT.ActivityDate, 0),                               AS [EOM],
    AVG(SUM(NetPrePaidActivations)) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY EOMONTH(WT.ActivityDate, 0))         AS [Average Prepaid]
FROM WalmartWSP.dbo.WalmartTransactions WT
LEFT JOIN WalmartWSP.dbo.RepRoster RR 
    ON  WT.repid = RR.RepID
    AND RR.RepHireDate BETWEEN '06-01-2022' AND '12-31-2022'
WHERE 
    WT.repid <> 0
    AND WT.ActivityDate BETWEEN '06-01-2022' AND '12-31-2022'
GROUP BY WT.repid, EOMONTH(WT.ActivityDate, 0)
```

Notes:

- if you *do* mean a `left join` on `RepRoster`, then you need to move the date filtering to the `ON` clause of the join (not in the `WHERE` clause, where it would filter rows that did not match in the join)
- don't use single quotes for identifiers (such as column names); the SQL standard reserves `'` for literal strings, although some databases diverge
- in a multi-table query, always qualify all columns with the table they come from, so the query is easier to understand (some of the columns in the `SUM()` are not prefixed)